# Chrome Element clicking problems, pageFactory framework solution

Tags: webdriver

I am having issues with Chrome throwing element stale, element not click able other element would receive click. My question more so has to do with pageFactory framework.

Given that chromedriver has these issues I would need to rewrite the selectors with offsets and other functionality to make it able to be click able correctly.

Should I make new xxxxPage.class's specifically for chrome? Or should I just incorporate all the chrome fixes into the current xxxxPage class, knowing that it will most likely work in firefox?

Or I can make a copy of the "SignIn" function for example with chrome fixes.

Basically what is the best way of keeping your final test code clean, with these changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective the page object should describe the page elements and not should be depends to the concrete driver implementation. I suggest to implement the helper common class that contains some common methods and then the specific classes that contains the specific implementation per browser. Then in your page object you will call the one  common function which will call the required to the driver class/method. In other words you will encapsulate the specific driver behaviour in the specific classes and the common class will decide what specific class will called.